# python stdout redirection and returncode

Tags: python, redirect, stdout, return-code

Can't get return code of subprocess with "global" redirection of stdout to log file:
F.e.:

```
    >>> rc = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c1', 'google.com'])
    PING google.com (173.194.69.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from bk-in-f102.1e100.net (173.194.69.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=86.1 ms
    --- google.com ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 86.141/86.141/86.141/0.000 ms
    >>> rc
    0
```

**rc** is **0** and i can work with it, BUT if do:

```
    >>> sys.stdout=open('/var/log/test','a')
    >>> rc = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c1', 'google.com'])
    PING google.com (173.194.69.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from bk-in-f102.1e100.net (173.194.69.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=86.9 ms
    --- google.com ping statistics --- 
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 86.947/86.947/86.947/0.000 ms
    >>> rc
    >>> sys.stdout.flash()
```

1st - rc goes to file, and not in view of script anymore. So I can't work with it.

2nd - only after sys.stdout.flash()

3rd - ping result goes to file only if i do

```
 rc = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c1', 'google.com'],stdout=sys.stdout)
```

The main question is how to prevent redirection of return code to stdout file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just redirect the output of ping to the file?

```
 rc = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c1', 'google.com'],stdout=open('/var/log/test','a'))
```

Or write rc to stderr instead:

```
print >> sys.stderr, rc
```

Comment: Bcs this example is just a part of the script with a lot of output which I want to redirect to a log file. And script depends on return-code of ping.

Comment: You'll get the return code no matter where you send stdout to. If you want to print the return code, use the `stderr` example. Or are you running the Python script from another script as well?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `commands.getstatusoutput`?

```
>>> commands.getstatusoutput('ping 8.8.8.8 -c1')
(0, 'PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=48 time=29.7 ms\n\n--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.790/29.790/29.790/0.000 ms')
```

The output is a tuple `status_code/output`.

Comment: Thank You, probably this is what I should use.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me rc **does** got the return value, but since you have overridden your process's stdout, the following line writes the value of rc to the log file:

```
>>> rc
```

As a side note, for scripts running subprocesses, redicrections, etc., I highly recommend using plumbum.